# How create an apk with icons replacement for another apk

Tags: java, android, icons, apk

I search a way to make a apk who can change default icons of my first apk. Like ADW Launcher for example.

How can I do this ? Maybe a way to take drawables of another apk ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i suppose what you looking for is Content Provider , http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

Comment: It's exactly what i'm looking for!! Thanks a lot!
How can i know the CONTENT_URI of my content provider ? If another dev add a extention I need to detect the content URI used by this apk

Comment: i never used ContentProvider this way (for me it was always for the system) but i guess this is a good start http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html#creating